# Flutter pop until reaching modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

In Flutter, I need to pop the route stack until I get to a modal bottom sheet, but I can't figure out how to do that using [Navigator.popUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) .

The scenario is this: I have a settings screen (lets call it `SettingsScreen`) which you can reach in a number of different ways from the main `HomeScreen`, resulting in a different stack of routes in the navigator. So for example the stack could be:

```
HomeScreen -> ScreenA -> SettingsScreen
```

or

```
HomeScreen -> ScreenA -> ScreenB -> SettingsScreen
```

Now I need a way to pop until I get to the HomeScreen. Normally I would achieve this using:

```
Navigator.popUntil(
   context,
   (Route<dynamic> route) => route.settings.name == "HomeScreen"
);
```

But here's the catch: sometimes there will be a modal bottom sheet open in the `HomeScreen`, and I need that to **remain open**. Since a modal bottom sheet is a route on the stack, if the sheet is open, the stack might be for example:

```
HomeScreen -> _ModalBottomSheetRoute<dynamic> -> ScreenA -> ScreenB -> SettingsScreen
```

So popping until I hit the `HomeScreen` causes the modal bottom sheet to pop, which closes it. So, I need to pop until I get to the `HomeScreen` **OR** until I get to `_ModalBottomSheetRoute<dynamic>`.

Unfortunately the bottom sheet route has no name or arguments in it's settings, and the runtime type of `_ModalBottomSheetRoute<dynamic>` is private so I can't even use that as a test. So how do I change the logic in `Navigator.popUntil` to stop when it gets to the modal bottom sheet? Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

how about passing route settings to showModalBottomSheet(... routeSettings: RouteSettings(name: 'MyModalBottomSheet'))? You could then test for the name given in popupUntil....